# breadcrumbs in expressionengine

Tags: navigation, expressionengine

I am using the crumbly add on for my breadcrumbs in expressionengine. I would like the add on to display the parent category if child category is displayed.

the URL would look like the following:

```
1. http://test/test1/news    and the parent category is the news.
2. http://test/test1/births  and the births is the subcategory for news.
```

I would like my navigation to look like the following (if the user is currently seeing the births)

```
test/ test1/ news / births
```

I need to highlight that this is done dynamically on each page.

Regards and thanks!

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest just using this excellent module:

[Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat)

However, your URL is not nesting categories so you'll need to use this module

[Category URL](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-url)

To output your category links, then use the Seg2Cat to grab the {segment_url} and manually build your crumbs for the news page i.e.

home > News > **Parent > Child > Article Title**

Would be something like:

{segment_2_category_name} {segment_3_category_name} {segment_4_category_name}